# Сравнение значения label и элементов listView

Tags: c#

Получаю имена нужных процессов. В `label11` хранится имя процесса активного окна. Нужно сравнить каждое имя процессов с именем процесса активного окна. Но получается, что сравнивается только 1 элемент. У меня их 2, а может быть и больше.

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
if (process != null)
{
//Сравниваем полученные ID с ID активного окна
if (label11.Text != process.ProcessName)
{
   if (timer1.Enabled == false)
   {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        _stopWatch.Start();
   }
}
else
{
   timer1.Enabled = false;
   _stopWatch.Stop();
}
}
```

ПОПРАВКА: он сравнивает только последний элемент

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами написали в своем коде:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
```

т.е. в переменной `process` хранится только 1 процесс. Если вы хотите получить все процессы с именем `processName`, то вы должны сделать так:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName); 

foreach (var process in processes)
{
    if (process != null)
    {
        //Сравниваем полученные ID с ID активного окна
        if (label11.Text != process.ProcessName)
        {
           if (timer1.Enabled == false)
           {
               timer1.Enabled = true;
               _stopWatch.Start();
           }
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        _stopWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Я немного пересмотрел свой способ и убрал получение процесса по имени. Т.е. сейчас в массиве лежат имена процессов `var processNames = new[] { "winword", "excel", "chrome", "photoshop" };` а дальше примерно тоже самое, только `label11` сравнивается с `processName`. И все равно работает только по последнему процессу.

Comment: Ваш способ не подходит, скорей всего из-за того, что данные представлены в виде массива. А `GetProcessesByName` ругается если ставить его без `FirstOrDefault()`. Ну или я делаю что-то не так :)